# Is it possible to run Windows 7 on a Lenovo T42?

Tags: windows-7, thinkpad

My brother has got a very old Lenovo T42 laptop, and he asked me to install Windows 7 on it but 
I'm not sure it can run it. So my question is: Can a laptop so old run Windows 7?

Specs

- 15.1" screen size
- 1 GB RAM
- 100 GB HDD
- 1.7 GHz single core
- HD 9600 64 MB

And can I just use RAM from my Asus N53J? Normal 204-pin?

Comment: What's with "Windows 7 or 8". Seems to me you are asking if it can run Windows 7 only. Did you mean XP or 7, Vista or 7?

Comment: Max out the RAM at least, and if you want a nice boost replace the HDD with an SSD and watch it fly!

Answer (score 5):

I believe that it may be able to run Windows 7, but you're looking at the bare minimum there. If you were to install it, make sure to purchase the 32-Bit version of the OS and disable any type of extra graphics like Aero and switch it to Windows Classic theme.

You can also download the [Windows 7 Upgrade Advisor](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=20) to see if it is compatible.

Comment: +1 For the upgrade advisor. You should look at that.

Answer (score 5):

Try it and see. From the specs given it ought to run Windows7 without any problems, although it's towards the low end of the requirements, so it might be a bit slow when running lots of programs.

Interestingly you might prefer to try running Windows8 on it; Windows was substantively rewritten in order to work better on low-end devices like tablets for Windows8, so you might find (counter-intutively) that upgrading past Windows7 might be better for your old machine than going just to Win7.

If you've just got a new laptop you should be formatting and reinstalling the whole OS anyway, and if there's some good reason why Windows won't be able to run on that machine, the OS installer will tell you and abort.

Comment: Yes that is true. I found that Windows 8 ran wonderfully on my pathetic netbook. 1 GB of RAM, Intel Atom Core, all that jazz. It actually ran better than XP. Quite amazing really.

Answer (score 0):

I would try this if the system meets everything this has then yes his computer can run windows 7. [Windows 7 Upgrade Advisor](http://windows.microsoft.com/is-IS/windows/downloads/upgrade-advisor)

Answer (score 0):

Your specs say you can install W7 on your laptop... Try 32-bit version and get Upadtes. You will probably have to install some drivers manually, but I think it will work.

Answer (score 0):

My T41 is currently running 32 bit Windows 7.  It is my understanding that 32 bit Windows 8.x might run too.  It will not run Windows 10.  Lenovo published an upgrade document on ThinkPads running Windows 7.  This document recommends updates to bios and firmware before going to Windows 7, both of which I applied.  I also upgraded my RAM to 2 GB (min required) and replaced the original 30 GB HDD with 120 GB SSD.  I also reduced the windows graphics effects to increase performance since my graphics chip is bottom end.

Answer (score 0):

Yes is great!. Install with a Win7 iso via an *Easy2Boot equipped USB and the install is a cinch. Use *'Snappy Driver Installer' with the torrent loaded driver pack off a USB also for ease of setup. The native Radeon 7500 isn't seen in full (!) in Device Drivers (you still get 1024x768 32bit but not as quick) so try adding one of the other Radeon 9500x drivers instead and cludge it - worked for me.

I Only have 1Gb installed and may get a 2Gb set as it runs pretty good. Typically those ultra slow and heavy resources Browsers like Chrome and Mozilla slow the online experience, but may be better with more RAM. Installed onto an 80Gb PATA (40 pin eide)  but other users get great results with a 240Gb mSata and mSata/Pata interface caddy.

https://www.easy2boot.com/
https://sdi-tool.org/

my W7 Experience index is as follows but remember is dictated by the lowest component score and here is 3D gaming = 1.0 !

cpu 3.2
RAM 4.0
Graphics 1.9
Gaming 1.0
Disk 4.4